# React app suddenly is using more than 1 GB of RAM on Chrome

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I've been working on an app I'm building, and until now it's had a reasonably small footprint. Today, however, I was looking into why my computer was suddenly running slowly, and I can see the app in Chrome is occupying around 1.2 GB of RAM!

Looking through my commits, I can't really spot anything suspicious. Where should I look when trying to debug enormous memory usage? I'd post code examples, but I can't see anything relevant, really.

Comment: Chrome devtools has a Performance tab that has a memory footprint option. I'd recommend using that, it's possible you have a memory leak somewhere

Answer (score 2):

To check what React is doing, try go get a snapshot of your app using the React profiler: *[Introducing the React Profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html)*

[image: Profiler]

For everything else, try checking out the built-in profiler in the Chrome developer tools: *[Chrome DevTools: JavaScript CPU Profiling in Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration)*

Those should be two good starting points to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, we might need some more clarification about what you've tried.

It could be a ton of things. Most likely you're storing some sort data from the server or have some sort of memory leak (like adding something to a collection, but never deleting it).

One thing you can do is use the Chrome profiler to see when your memory climbs:

(This can be found in the drawer that open when you push <kbd>Esc</kbd>.)

[image: The performance Profiler can be found in the Developer drawer, it might be under the ... of the thing that you push Esc to get to]

The "Performance" tab can also be nice if you want to view the memory on pageload (using the button). Just make sure that `memory` is checked.

Comment: It just appears to grow slowly over time, and never gets smaller. Is there some sort of garbage collection I'm meant to be doing? Contents of Redux state itself doesn't appear to be growing relative to the RAM usage.

Comment: If you have Redux Dev tools installed they might be the culprit for saving tons of memory: https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#will-having-one-state-tree-cause-memory-problems-will-dispatching-many-actions-take-up-memory However that's just another shot in the dark.